# Is it possible to display JMeter 'View Result In Table' listener data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have one JMeter test plan with several test cases. Also,I use jmeter-maven-plugin.
If one of  test cases fail (for 350 threads)  it looks [like](http://ci.jtalks.org/job/JC.%20Run%20Load%20tests/lastBuild/console)

```
Tests Run: 1, Failures: 350, Errors: 0
```

So it not clear what test case is failed.
Is it possible to show more detail information about failed test case in Jenkins UI or in the console? Exactly like the 'View Result In Table' listener show it in the JMeter GUI.
Is there a plugin to show formatted output for resulting JTL-file (only about test case status and fail details) in the console or in Jenkins UI?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this Jenkins Plugin: [Performance](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The code that checks for failures is just searching through your jtl file and looking for instances of failure, nothing more.  It's really just there so that you can trigger a failure that maven can detect, the plugin does not do in depth analysis of the .jtl file.

There is also a [jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin](https://github.com/afranken/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin) that will give you some more detailed information about the test results, if this doesn't meet your need feel free to add feature requests.